# Copy data from one table to another without duplicates based on more then one column comparision

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am stuck in the following query. This was working properly on mySQL but it gives error on MSSQL-2005. The main purpose of the query is to copy data from one table to another without duplicates based on multiple columns comparison from both tables.

I can do this to compare one column for duplication, but I can't do when I compare more then one column for duplication.

Here is my query.

```
INSERT INTO eBayStockTaking (OrderLineItemID,Qty,SKU,SubscriberID,eBayUserID) 
SELECT OrderLineItemID,Qty,SKU,SubscriberID,eBayUserID 
FROM tempEBayStockTaking WHERE (OrderLineItemID,SubscriberID,eBayUserID) 
Not In (SELECT OrderLineItemID,SubscriberID,eBayUserID FROM eBayStockTaking)
```

Note: I have been through many similar questions but all in vain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather try `NOT EXISTS`

Something like

```
INSERT INTO eBayStockTaking (OrderLineItemID,Qty,SKU,SubscriberID,eBayUserID) 
SELECT  OrderLineItemID,
        Qty,
        SKU,
        SubscriberID,
        eBayUserID 
FROM    tempEBayStockTaking t
WHERE   Not EXISTS  (
                        SELECT  *
                        FROM    eBayStockTaking e
                        WHERE   e.OrderLineItemID = t.OrderLineItemID
                        AND     e.SubscriberID = t.SubscriberID
                        AND     e.eBayUserID = t.eBayUserID) 
                    )
```

I know MySQL allows [Row Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html), nut SQL Server does not allow this.

Comment: Wouldn't be there any performance issue as compare to "Not In" method?

Comment: Multi-column sub queries such as in MySQL **DOES NOT EXIST** in SQL Server